# How to get path of a file in android Matlab

Tags: android, matlab

I have downloaded  matlab android version
And want to use this

I=imread(' path ');

I have a image file (s.jpg) in my internal storage 
But don't know whats the path address

I tried:

'sdcard/s.jpg'

'Phone/s.jpg'

'sdcard/emulate/0/s.jpg'

But it gives error that it doesn't exist

Comment: I tried even /storage/emulated/0/s.jpg

Comment: It should be given in the image details

Comment: It is written Phone/s.jpg but thats not working